# In DOORS Next Generation, can I get a notification when an artifact or module has changed?

Tags: ibm-doors

Is there a way to subscribe to an artifact or module so that I get a notification when that artifact or module has changed?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not able to find a similar feature like "subscribe" in Rational Team Concert for Work Items.

Usually, you solve this issue by:

- using "recently changed requirements" widget (it is not sending notifications).
- create a view that will list your requirements (with proper tags) in order by modification date.

Hope it will answer your question.